# Building windows store application in Delphi 11 failing

Tags: delphi, msix, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to build an Ad Hoc Windows Store application in Delphi 11 (MSIX), but I'm getting an error when I try to build the MSIX file.

> [PAClient Error] Error: E5128 MakeAppx : error: Error info: error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 6, Column 13, Reason: '%projectName%' violates pattern constraint of '[-.A-Za-z0-9]+'.

> [PAClient Error] Error: E5128 The attribute 'Name' with value '%projectName%' failed to parse.

And indeed, in the `AppxMainifest.xml` file, on line 6, contains `%projectName%`.

I'm presuming that there is something in the version info that I need to set, but I'm not sure what.  Does anyone know?

There is also

```
<DisplayName>%packageDisplayName%</DisplayName>
<PublisherDisplayName>%publisherDisplayName%</PublisherDisplayName>
```

That don't seem to be replaced.

Comment: They should be after you use an existing certificate or create a self signed certificate.

Comment: Yes, I have a self-signed certificate installed.

Comment: Try selecting distribution type: store and filling in package name there. Then switch back to ad hoc.

Comment: Looks like you do need to fill in the fields under Distribution type with store selected then switch back to Ad hoc. Confusing UI.

Comment: Missing details in the Store distribution type does indeed seem to be it.  If they are required for Ad hoc testing, I don't know why it's not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

They're a bit hidden under Provisioning section:
[image]

but they're for the Store, for Ad-hoc it should get them from your self-signing certificate I guess:
[image]